# How to get result of @CanActivate?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**Is it possible to get the value of child route's `@CanActivate` from parent or root route?**

I have several routes with different `@CanActivate` conditions. They work after app is initialized, but my issue is with initial loading. When I open a browser with path that points to one of the routes that can't be activated:

```
@CanActivate(() => false)
```

the component isn't loaded, which is good. I would like to redirect to the root in this case, but I can't find good condition to check. I tried few things:

- `useAsDefault: true` on parent component - no effect
- private `this._router._currentInstruction` - no effect, it is `null` for both `@CanActivate(() => false)` and `@CanActivate(() => false)` on child components
- `routerOnActivate()` on parent/root component - no effect, it's never called with `@CanActivate(() => false)` on child component

#### Update:

Tried even with `Reflect`, but it seams router doens't reference an actual component, but creates a `componentType` "copy":

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let url = this._router.lastNavigationAttempt;
    this._router.recognize(url).then(resolvedInstruction => {
      let component = resolvedInstruction.child.component.componentType;
      let canActivate = Reflect.getMetadata("CanActivate", component.constructor);
      console.log(canActivate); // => undefined
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating `linkParams` when previous `ComponentInstruction` is `null`, and then instructing router to navigate using those params.

It's a bit complex solution (using @ngrx/store, static class method, injector...), but it's a part of large application and I like *write-once-and-forget-about-it* approach (:

It is, however, easy to use:

```
@CanActivate((next, prev) => {
  return _BaseRoute.canActivate(true, next, prev );
})
export class ChildRoute extends _BaseRoute { 
  constructor(public store: Store<any>) {
    super();
  }
}
```

The rest of the code is in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sasxa/c4cc7ba2e203c7d91106). If anyone finds better solution, I'll gladly accept the answer.